# adding a method and html options to link_to in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm brand new to ruby and rails and I'm having trouble creating a sign-out link (using devise for auth).  I want to pass a custom :method parameter into the link_to function, and set a custom class.  I seem to be able to do one or the other but not both.

When I try:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, { :class => 'signout'}   %>
```

I get the proper result from clicking the link, but I lose my styling.  On the other hand, when I try:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, { :class => 'signout'}, :method => :delete %>
```

I get the styling I want but the link request is passed as GET rather than DELETE, resulting in  a routing error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try placing both `:class` and `:method` inside the hash.

So:
`<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, { :class => 'signout', :method => :delete} %>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need hash here, because it is already hash :D

```
link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: "delete", class: "signout"
```

profit!

Comment: Good to know thanks!  So is the hash always optional with named parameters like this?

Comment: only in cases if the hash is a last parameter in a method in Ruby

Comment: @sak They're not named parameters (Ruby doesn't have those), you're just allowed to omit the `{}` when the final parameter for the method is a hash.